# How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?

Tags: support, faq, left-navigation

There is a new left navigation sidebar.

[image]

I prefer using the space for reading questions. How do I hide it?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 358, accepted):

### How to hide the left navigation sidebar

1. Click your **reputation** on the top bar
2. Click the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab
3. Click **Preferences** under Site Settings
4. Click the **Hide left navigation** checkbox

Or just click here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/

[image]

### Notes

- The instructions above only work if you're signed into an account.
- You can still get to the navigation items by clicking the menu icon on the top left.
  [image]