# Make left navigation sidebar items "sticky"

Tags: feature-request, left-navigation

Having seen [How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369106/2096401) and its answer, it struck me that there's room for improvement in how the left sidebar and/or the menu-icon works:

**Sidebar Visible**

- The menu-items are not absolutely anchored, so they scroll out of view as you move down the page. If you want to use the sidebar, you have to scroll back to the top of the page.

**Sidebar Hidden**

- The replacement menu icon is always visible in the top-bar (unless stickiness has been turned off) so is always available.

**Proposal**

When enabled, make the items in the sidebar menu "stick" to the top of the page (in the same way the "*How to Format*" and "*Similar Questions*" boxes displayed on the right are fixed when asking a question).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> This is about the "desktop" view: I've not tried it on a mobile.

<sup>**2**</sup> A *possible* alternative would be to always make the menu-icon visible, even if the sidebar is displayed, but I think I would prefer that less.

Comment: Would be nice if we could close questions as a cross-site dupe: [the MSE question about the new left side nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness). This has been posted in one of the answers there i believe (if not, go ahead)

Comment: @AndréKool Sorry, I didn't realise that thread was there (I ass.u.me.d that because the question I linked was on SO.meta here was the right place for mine :-(). [**This is the relevant answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310913/213468). Should I delete this (or, perhaps, add that link to the question)?

Comment: Deleting is up to you (or the community (or a mod)), I just pointed you to the best place to post such a feature request :)

Comment: By "absolutely anchored" I assume you mean `position: fixed` or `position: sticky`.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes... at the moment they scroll out of view on a long page; I'd prefer them to be fixed in place.

Comment: I was just clarifying that you didn't mean `position: absolute` because that would definitely not give you the result you're asking for.

Comment: @TinyGiant I was probably subconsciously (and possibly erroneously) thinking `position:absolute` might be involved, but I don't play with CSS much so could easily be mistaken. The goal is for the navigation list to always be visible on the left however much the main page scrolls.