# Can the sidebar be removed?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, user-experience

The left-hand sidebar is a terrible waste of screen real estate. As are arguably the top navbar and the right-hand sidebar.

I'd guess that most devs are on laptops with limited screen real estate, although I have no evidence for this.

Can the left-hand sidebar be removed?

Arguably all we need on the screen are questions, answers, adverts and a hamburger menu with links behind it.

**Edit:** this question is actually slightly different to the others. I am asking whether sidebar can be removed from the site entirely because the UX is atrocious.

I'll admit I didn't know there was a setting to hide it, but my question still stands.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369140/make-left-navigation-sidebar-items-sticky

Comment: Fine, I'll continue to use a Chromium Plugin to hack the site CSS in the browser. The current UX is from the 1990s.

Comment: Why? just go into your profile and disable it.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do that!

Comment: You can also avoid using it at all by adopting the usage of keyboard shortcuts to navigate the site. For example, g q takes you to the questions page.

Comment: Another CSS thing I'm hacking is a dark mode. Is there a dark mode setting?

Comment: @Ben see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386150/should-stack-overflow-revisit-the-dark-mode-question-in-light-of-new-situations