# Allow logged-out users to hide the left navigation bar

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, left-navigation

The instructions in the proposed FAQ [How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar) only work if the user is logged into an account.

I propose that we allow another method to give users who don't have accounts or are logged out the ability to hide this sidebar. This is also useful to users like me who occasionally browse the site in their browser's private mode.

Comment: I think this should be posted on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness)

Comment: @AndreKool The left navigation bar is enabled only on SO, so this would be off-topic there as they only deal with issues affecting multiple network sites. SE staff do check per-site metas.

Comment: Please chck the post I linked. It's about the left side nav and it will be comming to all stack sites. And all feedback should be posted there.

Comment: @AndreKool I'll post an answer on the MSE question, but this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Well, I think this whole navigation bar thing, just like the other recent "improvements", are essentially the manifestation of the collective urge to do the site better - while some "super" boss forbids all changes.

Comment: ublock might do the trick.

Comment: In my opinion it would be better if the new vertical navigation bar is hidden by default for everyone. If it's really useful I expect to see most people to voluntarily enable the so called new "feature".

Comment: You barintolerants, we need more bars. I want a bar on the bottom as well. I want multibar options. Bars inside of bars. Bars that maximize, bars in dynamic layouts, multi screen bars, and naturally, bars that serve the martini shaken. It goes on forever — and — oh my God! — it's full of bars!

Comment: Shouldn't this be [meta-tag:status-declined]? Feature requests can't be by-design.

Comment: @Dukeling https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7023024#7023024

Answer (score -7):

The ability to hide the left nav is a feature for signed in users only by design. We are currently relying on account preferences to manage pinned/unpinned state. We'd need to implement it a different way to support anonymous users and change the UX model which adds some complexity. Ultimately, we decided this wasn't critical.

Comment: Does this work for unregistered, cookie-based accounts?

Comment: AFAIK, it *should*, @gparyani - but feel free to test it!

Comment: I'm sorry to see that this won't be changed. It's a bad design. StackOverflow is not a critical part of my life, and I don't really need it. I'll be minimizing my use of stack-overflow because of this change, if not dropping it altogether. Please rethink this policy.

Comment: @Joe if this is not critical (and in itself introduce conplexity) why force this upon users in the first place?