# Sidebar on stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, left-navigation

I was clicking through my favorite tags just now and noticed the page suddenly changed format and has a sidebar showing up. I'm wondering if I might've clicked something else to suddenly trigger this, or is it some type of new feature or format?

[image]

Will there be an option to hide it or turn it off?

Comment: I _just_ noticed it too and came here to ask the same question. Looks like it's a new interface?

Comment: As for your question on how you can hide it, that is explained here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar