# Is there way to switch to the old UI of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-interface

I like the old UI of Stack Overflow more, having one sidebar and a menu on top. The current UI makes me feel like there is less focus on valuable information. Maybe this is a just personal thing. So I was just wondering, is there a way to roll back to the old UI by myself?

Comment: I find the bigger problem is with viewing the full site on a mobile device.  There, the new layout is pretty bad, and makes it hard to work.  Is there any chance that the old UI would still be available on mobile devices?

Comment: Why would SO support multiple UI code bases for their website? I mean, maintaining both mobile and desktop are bad enough (and what this project is aiming to remove). I can't see why they would want to maintain two more...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Because they might want to keep their customers? Alternatively they could simply rollback the changes.

Comment: Could be worse, SO could've used Reddit's UI redesign team.

Comment: @Lundin I think this is the classic "Who moved my cheese?" stuff that goes on during any redesign. You can't make everybody happy.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No, they have simply been doing numerous very bad UI changes over the past half a year. SO layout has always been changing, but mostly for the better, until somewhere 2017 where it derailed. Now they just try to mimic social media layout trends like "monochrome icons" instead of using  common sense.

Comment: I don't mind the left sidebar, but I *really* don't like how the right sidebar suddenly moved to the bottom when viewing on narrow display (be it mobile or desktop half-screen). Having question timestamp and views, HMP's (aka "community bulletin"), linked/related, and HNQ's underneath the "post your answer" button just doesn't feel right.

Comment: You could grab the styles, JS, etc from the old UI (via archive.org if needed) and probably hack something together using user styles and scripts, but that would probably be super brittle, prone to bugs and not fare well on future SO updates. But you don't *need* to use the stylesheets their webserver provides.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the left panel (in *Preferences* in tab "_Settings" on your user profile), checkbox *Hide left navigation*?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan There is more of the classic case "why is the cheese blocking my view?"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's a temporary fix. My understanding is that they're figuring out a better solution.

Comment: @Catija I'm sure paying advertisers are thrilled to have their ads shown at the bottom of the screen where nobody ever needs to scroll =)...actually, I'm not even seeing the ad slot in the reactive UI..

Comment: @MathieuGuindon not sure ads have anything to do with it. Responsive design includes mobile, which generally doesn't see them at all.

Comment: Sure does. Until recently I could request desktop/full site on mobile (never liked the mobile layout) and see them. Now I don't even see them on desktop if I dock the browser to half the monitor width.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Well, that's at least partially because they haven't actually done the part of the design for smaller screens/mobile devices. It's still in progress with a lot of the other pages. See the paragraph that starts with "This is a work in progress". https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness It's in bold. :) There's a lot of good documentation about this change on MSE>

Comment: Fair enough. Still falls under "fixing what's not broken" IMO.

Comment: I also don't like the new UI, but fortunately I can hide Left Navigation in Preferences of each site....... :-)

Comment: I take it you've figured out how to disable the stupid left nav bar by now, yes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For right now, you sort of can. But it's temporary. My understanding is that once the update is actually complete (it's still in testing/development right now), you won't have the option any longer.

Check the footer of any page that has the new site layout, it's the last link under the site name:

[image: Disabling responsiveness in footer fourth link under "Stack Overflow"]

Couple this with [disabling the left sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar) and that's as close as you can get. Note, that you have to disable the sidebar on each site/meta site as it's not a global setting.

Comment: All this does is remove the responsiveness from the page.  The side bar and the new elements of the layout persist.

Comment: You can also turn off the left sidebar... which is the other half of the equation. Doing both is *mostly* the same.

Comment: Well least I can hide the Left Sidebar. Thanks @Catija I think this a good answer

Comment: What is this link supposed to do? Clicking it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Dukeling If your browser page width is set so that you have white bars on either side, you won't notice a difference. Make your page width narrower and you'll see how it's different... you get a side scroll instead of the responsive design.

Comment: That is one of the most useless (and/or weird - not sure) link I have seen in my life.

Comment: The link seems to work for me... just goes to another post on MSO. ::shrug::

Comment: SPOILER:this answer won't help bring old UI back.

Comment: @Viney That implies that anything will... :) Also, not really a "spoiler". First sentence says "sort of".

Comment: @Catija I tried many times but the result was no different than pressing some random link on the website :p might be due to using Opera browser?

Comment: If they want to test something that's not yet done but "work in progress", it is fine to use the meta.stack* sites as guinea pigs. Not the main SO site.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't switch back to the old UI at all.

Comment: Why does this have 40 upvotes if it doesn't seem to work for anyone?

Comment: @MCMastery It works just fine as long as what you want is no sidebar on the left and you do want to be able to side scroll the page rather than having the page change width. It's the closest you can get with the options presented by the site.

Comment: @Catija hmm, it doesn't seem to remove the sidebar for me.

Comment: If you follow the instructions on the post I linked, @MCMastery ? I *think* I've heard a few people are experiencing a bug with it but I'm not certain. In general, you have to click that option on every site as it's not global (there are requests to make it global, too) - "every" meaning three at the moment.