# Is there a way to revert to the old SO UI?

Tags: support, feature-request

I noticed a recent change in Stack Overflow's User Interface, and was wondering if there's a way to revert to the old UI. I know that [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369401/is-there-way-to-switch-to-the-old-ui-of-stack-overflow) asks this same thing, but it seems to be outdated, as the update I'm referring to was within the last few weeks.

So is there a way to revert to the old UI? If not, could that be a feature in settings?

Comment: @IanCampbell Thank you for that link. However, I was thinking more along the lines of a built-in feature, not just a script that you can run on the page.

Comment: As I mentioned in that question's comments, why would Stack Overflow spend money maintaining every version of each UI they produce? How far back should the option go? You saw that old question, when the option to "revert to old UI" is checked, which "old UI" should it revert to? The one that was old when that question was asked, or when this question was asked? Or maybe a dropdown of every version of the UI code? Seems like a bigger ask now?

Comment: @HereticMonkey That would make sense, although it's not like they'd have to spend a ton of time programming the old UIs, seeing as they've already been made. It'd just take up a bit more storage and maybe a PHP script. But I feel that a dropdown menu would be a good idea, and that's why I also tagged this post as "feature request". If they're going to add the feature, they could start with the UI that is used at the time of making the feature, and go from there.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el

Comment: Very surely, there is none. They want to push it down on your throat, not helping you to avoid it.

Comment: For years the requests for a dark mode were rejected simply because they did not want to maintain multiple stylesets for the site. We actually did get one eventually. Do you really think they will want to maintain an old style UI light/dark and a new style UI light/dark? I'd be willing to put a good bet on "heck no".

Comment: eh, this design is being done literally for the purpose of not needing to maintain a dozen different layouts. the old layout being old doesn't mean it wouldn't take work to keep it.

Comment: @Gimby Some "SO unofficial" repository could be created by userscripts and css files... I can not remember a UI change since 2014 for which I had said, it was well done.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Another option would be to develop the site UI on a way, that the consecutive UIs are always better, than the previous ones. That would remove the need to switch back. It would be also useful to attract content and contributors.

Comment: @peterh Well, I think that's the goal of this most recent change, eventually. But many people don't like when things change, irrespective of the change. So they ask for the old UI back. One person's "better" is another person's "worse".

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hence the option to revert back to the old UI.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, this is the very good excuse of the responsible SO employee to sell their crap. And their bosses, not knowing the site neither the UX, believe that. But we know. This is why you can not sell the same s..t to me.