# New sidebar design on all SE sites

Tags: support, left-navigation

I don't understand what utility does it serve besides being a distracting feature while reading a post.

Why has this been added and can there a configurable option to hide it if not removing completely?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar

Comment: Yes, there is an option: Look in your Preferences.

Comment: Also read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes

Answer (score -4):

[image: Hide side navigation bar]

The navigation bar can be hidden from the [preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/)