# New left nav is too wide and aligned to nothing?

Tags: feature-request

Is it my screen's resolution or is the left nav unnecessarily wide and seemingly aligned to nothing? It should be either:

1. Aligned with the upper grey rectangle that contains the `stackoverflow` logo.
2. More narrow

[image]

Comment: yeah, I'm not a fan of it

Comment: Related: [How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar)

Comment: Didn't know I could hide it. Thanks @TravisJ!