# How do I make the central question panel larger?

Tags: support, user-interface, user-experience

I read this answer to hide the nav bar: *[How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar)*

Which I have done, but now it just leaves a huge white gap:

[image]

Just so everybody knows I wanted to remove the scrollbars on the code block.

Comment: But the nav bar is gone, right?

Comment: CSS injection....Stylish here we come!

Comment: @usr2564301 yes it is, but it didn't actually achieve my goal of making the central panel larger

Comment: AFAIK, SE never intends the main area to extend beyond approx. 660px for precise formatting purpose...

Comment: That's why you have to be specific when you make a wish to a genie.

Comment: Use a smaller monitor

Comment: I'd much rather have that whitespace than have to try and read a long paragraph of text as one line across my monitor, but I guess that's me...

Comment: I'd much rather not have to horizontally scroll code blocks, but I guess that's just me.

Comment: @HereticMonkey as Roddy says I was wanting to read a code block with long lines

Comment: It seems you only need to change the `max-width` of two elements, but don't ask me how to turn that into a userscript.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just be sure to be using version 2 and not version 3 of stylish (because it turned into spyware).

Comment: Hit `Ctrl +` to zoom and consume more space.

Comment: @WendyG how big is your screen? Mine worked ok?

Comment: @AndrewT. On inspection, width:auto; overrides the width:630px rule in the css....it's stricken through in my console ..

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm basing on [my observation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305031/241919) before the unified design though.

Comment: @RachelGallen it is a shiny new monitor 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 7):

You could check out my StackApp [VisualCrumbs](https://stackapps.com/questions/7933/visualcrumbs-stackexchange-visual-changes), it does this plus a few other visual changes to the site.

[image]

(Note: This works with Tampermonkey)

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use the [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) add-on for injections and manipulation of this kind -although it is proprietary for mozilla..

And don't forget to use regex's to parse the html and put a little jquery into the soup ;)

Comment: [Regexes to parse the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?

Comment: @hnefatl : sarcasm?